# Are there half-transitive convex polytopes?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, automorphisms

I only consider *convex polytopes*, i.e. convex hulls of finitely many points. The *(edge-)graph* of a polytope $P\subseteq\Bbb R^d$ is the graph consisting of the polytope's vertices, two are adjacent if they lie on a common edge in $P$.

The orthogonal symmetry group of $P$ induces a permutation symmetry group on its graph. We say that a polytope is *vertex*-, *edge*-, [*arc*-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph) and/or [*half-transitive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-transitive_graph) if the symmetry group induced on its graph acts in the respective way.

> **Question:** Are there *half-transitive* polytopes, i.e. polytopes which are vertex- and edge-transitive, but not arc-transitive?

I looked a bit into [chiral polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_polytope) (i.e. two flag orbits), but I read somewhere that these only exist for abstract polytopes, and not for convex ones. However, I think that chirality is a much stronger requirement for a polytope than half-transitivity (as the latter only speaks about vertices and edges instead of flags).

Comment: I don't see why the graph needs to be half-transitive. The symmetry group of the polytope might not induce the full group of the graph. Graphs with a half-transitive subgroup are much more common. (Cycles, for example.)

Comment: @verret You are absolutely right. I edited that part out.